# Change display of field.value on a per field basis?

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm using reusable form templates to manually render form fields and I want to display the *values* of the form fields in a specific way.

I'm looping over the fields in the form and filtering `field.value`  based on the field name which feels sloppy. I feel like I should be able to tie how a field's value displays to the field itself, not on conditional logic within the loop.

I've already tried making my fields Select widgets with explicit choices, but that has no effect on `field.value`, and that's what I want to display differently.

Here's what I'm currently doing:

```py
{% if field.name == 'sending_domain' %}
   {{ field.value | default:"[ANY DOMAIN]" }}
{% elif field.name == 'from_email' %}
   {{ field.value | default:"Not set. Required!"  }}
{% elif field.name == 'custom_api_key' %}
   {{ field.value | default:"Required custom API key not set."  }}
{% elif field.name == 'custom_subaccount' %}
   {{ field.value | default:"Not set."  }}
{% else %}
   {{ field.value | default:"None" }}
{% endif %}
```

That code works - Sending Domain displays "[ANY DOMAIN]" by default, From Email displays "Not set. Required!" by default, etc -  but it also hurts my soul. What's a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Normally a switch statement would be the more elegant solution. But to my understanding, python does not have switch statements.
[Article](https://www.pydanny.com/why-doesnt-python-have-switch-case.html)

I have a similar set of code in my latest project.

[Possible option](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/switch-case-in-python-replacement/)